# Why I get different result for inbuilt and defined FFT in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the code below for fft2 performed by numpy and a 2d fft performed by direct code. an anyone point out why they are different? My inputmatreix is rA.

```
def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * math.pi * 1J / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j ) / np.sqrt(N)
    return W

sizeM=40
rA=np.random.rand(sizeM,sizeM)
rAfft=np.fft.fft2(rA)

rAfftabs=np.abs(rAfft)+1e-9


dftMtx=DFT_matrix(sizeM)
dftR=dftMtx.conj().T
mA=dftMtx*rA*dftR

mAabs=np.abs(mA)+1e-9

print(np.allclose(mAabs, rAfftabs))
```

Comment: can u add the differing outputs to your question, along with comments denoting which is the input for your FFT and the builtin one?

Comment: @JohnD my input matrix is rA of size 40X40. By the way finally I need to perform 2 dimensional FFT by for loops as I need each dot product for my work.

Comment: You are comparing two methods, fft2 is a library that uses the butterfly, the DFT is a transformation that should yield the FFT. The result would be similar in shape,but I am not sure of the scale. Tip: don't analyse noise. You feed your FFT with a random matrix, so you are getting noise for both.Try your comparison with a controlled test input matrix that has some regularity and 0/1 values and see what happens.

Comment: @Goodies, I tried with ones but it is different, so there must be a mistake somewhere in my code. Can you pleas help? May I ask, what do you mean by butterfly?

Comment: Dunno if I can help, I don't see your test patterns and I don't see your result. Butterfly is an enumeration of the input in such a way, that it will allow to split your the FFT analysis in many smaller partial analyses. In DFT-terms: many smaller DFT-matrices. You seem to use a single DFT matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram

Comment: @Goodies Thank you for the link. In fact the smaller matrices would be very helpful for me. But I thought the result would be same and there must be a mistake in my code which I cannot find as I get false for the last print and image of mAabs and mAfftabs  is completely different when I plot them. Did not include the plot as it seems reduntant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your implementation.

#### 1. DFT Matrix formula

First of all, as explained [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Fourier_Analysis/node7.html), the formula for computing the DFT `X` of a `M`x`N` signal `x` is defined as:

[image]

Since you are computing the DFT for a `M`x`M` input, you just need to compute the `DFT_Matrix` once. Also note that due to the way `W` is defined, there is no need for conjugation and since `W` is symmetric and unitary there is no need for any transpose.

#### 2. Matrix multiplication

When it comes to actually multiplying the matrixes together, you have to make sure to use the matrix multiplication operator `@` instead of the element wise multiplier `*`

#### 3. DFT_matrix normalization

By default the `fft` functions don't normalize your output. This means that before comparing the two outputs, you either have to divide the `np.fft.fft2` result by `sqrt(M*M) = M` or you drop the  `np.sqrt(N)` in your `DFT_matrix` function.

#### Summary:

Her is your example with the appropriate fixes for a `M`x`N` input. At the end, the magnitudes and angles are compared.

```
import numpy as np

def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * np.pi * 1j / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j ) # Normalization by sqrt(N) Not included
    return W

sizeM=40
sizeN=20
np.random.seed(0)
rA=np.random.rand(sizeM,sizeN)

rAfft=np.fft.fft2(rA)


dftMtxM=DFT_matrix(sizeM)
dftMtxN=DFT_matrix(sizeN)

# Matrix multiply the 3 matrices together 
mA = dftMtxM @ rA @ dftMtxN


print(np.allclose(np.abs(mA), np.abs(rAfft)))
print(np.allclose(np.angle(mA), np.angle(rAfft)))
```

Both checks should evaluate to `True`. However note that the complexity of this algorithm, assuming `M=N` is `N³` while the library's `fft2` brings that down to `N²log(N)`!

Comment: Thank you so much, I never new that * is element wise and @ is matrix multiplication. I am too used to matlab.

Comment: My interest is in IFFT2 not FFT2. I was assuming that if I can implement fft2 by dft matrix I just need to change the negative sign in the line omega = np.exp(-  2 * np.pi * 1j / N ) to omega = np.exp( 2 * np.pi * 1j / N ) and everything will work. But it did not happen. Any idea why? Further I have found out that if I remove the line np.randon.seed(0) I get false on the angle(mA) and angle(rAfft). Absolute value is fine in this case as well, Do you know why? Please don't mind I am asking so many questions.

Comment: I am asking a new question so that I can give some credit.

Comment: I provide he answers in the reply to the new question